# Does Vim have support for "variable tabs"?

Tags: vim

I thought I saw some mention of it somewhere, but my searches recently came up with nothing constructive.

Generally, what I'm asking is - a set up so the first tab is on 10th column, the second on 23th, the third on 32th and so on ... you get the idea, surely ...

If anyone has any ideas, they'd be more than welcomed :)

Comment: @Randy Morris - Randy, hi. Why did you delete your answer? It looked interesting, to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is supported by [the SoftTabStops plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2797), though I cannot claim experience using it...